# Creating home screen browser shortcuts from android app

Tags: java, android

I have a php site, which is basically like a site directory, what I want to achieve is to create a home screen shortcuts from  when I click a URL in an application, meaning:
I need to first, intercept the url, decode it, and create a browser shortcut to a parameter within the url.

Thanks in advance, Itai.

Comment: Can you flesh this out a bit more, I'm a little confused - are we talking about intercepting clicks in a WebView within your app, or every time a known URL is clicked in any app?

Comment: Do you mean like this: to create a android app which let user create a browser shortcut on home screen for their favorite websites including parameters in website's url. ????? :-/

Comment: @Harry Joy, yes, to create on home screen a browser shortcut. However the button to create this shortcut is on a php page, so I need to intercept the <a href>

Comment: @Phil Lello, a WebView within my app, I know this is done using shouldOverrideUrlLoading, the problem is I don't understand how to create a shortcut from there on out. BTW - I'm a total Java newbie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite easy to make the shortcut,

```
final Intent i = new Intent(); //intent for the shortcut
final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent( /*put necessary parameters (i.e activity to launch)*/ );
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID /*if your launching a browser*/,
        Long.toString(/*put unique id e.g. system time etc.*/));
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, /*title*/);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,/*drawable*/);
i.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

for url interception, in a WebViewClient

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.equalsIgnoreCase(/*your sitemap url*/)) {
        //use the above code
    }
    return true;
}
```

I hope this helps. I have not tested this but this is the general idea! Good luck

Comment: This helped tremendously, however, I want the shortcut to be a browser bookmark (meaning that it'll use the favicon.ico, aswell as the title, of the page i'm making the shortcut too.

Comment: Hi Itai, glad this helped. Unfortunately, the above code is partially from one of my own browser apps and it would be bad business to release all the details, but I can give you a few pointers. For the favicon, WebViewClient.onReceivedIcon and webView.getFavicon() can help, convert to drawable and place it in the i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,/*drawable*/); section. The title you can get with webView.getTitle()